# Quarkus Message Addons with Smallrye Kafka Throws error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging, kogito

I have tried integrating Quarkus start and end with message using Smallrye Kafka.
But i am getting following error when i create kafka connections

```
 Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.kie.kogito.event.EventEmitter and qualifiers [@Default]
        - java member: com.example.MyendMessageProducer_1#emitter
        - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.kie.kogito.services.event.impl.AbstractMessageProducer<io.example.models.Location>, java.lang.Object, com.example.MyendMessageProducer_1], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.example.MyendMessageProducer_1]
        The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
                - Bean [class=org.kie.kogito.app.SampleeventsEventEmitter, qualifiers=[@SampleeventsQualifier, @Any]]
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1209)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.init(BeanDeployment.java:275)
        at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.initialize(BeanProcessor.java:134)
        at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.validate(ArcProcessor.java:494)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:944)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

I have added the addons pom dependency for messaging

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie.kogito</groupId>
      <artifactId>kogito-addons-quarkus-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The below are my properties for Kafka topics

```
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.topic=sample-events
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_stream.auto.offset.reset=earliest

mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_event.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_event.topic=new-event
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_event.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.kogito_incoming_event.auto.offset.reset=earliest

mp.messaging.outgoing.sample-events.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.sample-events.topic=sample-events
mp.messaging.outgoing.sample-events.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

mp.messaging.outgoing.sample_new_event.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.sample_new_event.topic=new-event
mp.messaging.outgoing.sample_new_event.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

quarkus.reactive-messaging.auto-connector-attachment=true
```

The below are my versions of various dependencies

```
 <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.10.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M7</surefire-plugin.version>
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: There was a configuration problem. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76383369/16843807)